# Save .gpx files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, leaflet, gpx

I want to implement a map with Leaflet to show the trace of a .gpx file in it.
I'm doing it with Laravel and I would like to save the file beacause it's the client itself that uploads it in the app.
I have to save it like an image in the /public directory or there is another way with this type of files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to save the gpx file that user uploads and then read it. I don't know how and where to save that file. Maybe it's better to keep it on Laravel public file system or better to save it on database?